# How can we change aws instances region from US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1 to Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, web-development-server

I deployed all my app on an Amazon EC2 instance in US East (N.Virginia). Now I want to move it to Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1 region.

I don't want to change my IP (which one I got from US East (N.Virginia)). And I don't want to lose any activity from the EC2 Instance.

Even I tried [Move an EC2 Instance to Another Subnet, Availability Zone, or VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/), but did not get anything.

How can we change this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't keep the public IP, amazon's regions have separate IP ranges. Route53 is one of the few services that is not region-bound. So if you assigned a DNS name, you can keep that DNS name. But what do you mean by losing activity? Is downtime allowed?

Comment: @GreyFairer activity means:- Suppose I installed docker and jenkins on that instances.If I chenge the region then is it gone or is it still there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Take the AMI of the existing machine.
2. Copy the AMI to the new region.
3. Launch new machine from the AMI.

NOTE: You can't keep the existing public IP because AWS has different set of IP's for different regions. To overcome this create a public domain in Route53 and create a A record and change the value of A record to new public IP, use your DNS name instead of public IP everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to take an image (AMI) of the instance in US-East-1 and copy the image to the target region (ap-south-1) and then launch the AMI in the ap-south-1 region.

From AWS console, do the following:

1. Go to EC2 console.
2. Clock 'Running instances'.
3. Find the instance you want to move.  Click the check box for that instance.
4. If you want to move the instance, shut it down here, first, by clicking Actions->Instance State-Stop
5. Actions->Image->Create Image
6. Give a name, optionally a description.
7. If you didn't previously shutdown the instance, you have an option of whether to reboot the box when taking AMI.
8. Click 'Create Image'.
9. Wait for the image creation to complete, and you can see the new AMI in the the AMI page of the EC2 console.
10. In the left column of the EC2 console, go to 'AMIs'.
11. When you see the new AMI in the list, and it's available, click the checkbox to the left of the name.
12. Actions->Copy AMI
13. For Desination Region, selECT 'Asia Pacific (Mumbai)'.
14. Enter name, description, and whether you want the AMI in the destination region to be encrypted.
15. Click 'Copy AMI'.
16. Wait for copy to complete.
17. Switch to ap-south-1 region.
18. Find the AMI and select it.
19. click 'Launch Instance'.
20. Make your choices.
21. Wait for instance to launch.

Lots of little steps, but it's actually pretty easy.